# Typed object literal with nested properties can't get intellisense to work

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, javascript-objects, intellisense

I'm trying to improve a project of mine with typescript and I can't figure out how to make the following to work.

Say that I have a function expression as simple as this

```
const foo = (objectLiteral: any): void => {
  console.log(objectLiteral)
}
```

Now, I'm just going to use it like so.

```
foo({
  name: 'guybrush',
  nestedProperties: {
    gunPowderAmount: 1
  },
  speak () {
    // First issue, "this" is any type. I don't get any intellisense for the properties 
    // within the object.
    // this.
  }
})
```

As from my comment inside the speak function, "this" has any type and I cannot access any of the properties of the object. This I believe is related to this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11072.

**I know this is not typescript related - yet - I'm getting there.**

Then I assumed, that since I'm using typescript, I can leverage types, cool! 
And so my code mutated to the following:

```
type MappedCharacter = {
  name: string;
  speak: () => void;
  nestedProperties: { [key: string]: number | string };
}

const foo2 = (objectLiteral: MappedCharacter) => {
  console.log(objectLiteral)
}
```

And I'm going to use it like so:

```
foo2({
  name: 'guybrush',
  nestedProperties: {
    gunPowderAmount: 1
  },
  speak () {
    // Second issue. Now "this" has access to the properties, but NOT
    // the one which are NESTED into "nestedProperties"
  }
})
```

Cool, I now have access to "this", and I can target the properties "name" and "nestedProperties".

But hey, "nestedProperties" has other properties! Where are them?

Final test, I'm going to get rid of the function expression, and just test the object on its own.

```
const objectLiteral: MappedCharacter = {
  name: 'guybrush',
  nestedProperties: {
    gunPowderAmount: 1
  },
  speak () {
    // Third issue. Even if not used in a function, "this.nestedProperties" can't dig any 
    // deeper.
    // this.nestedProperties.
  }
}
```

As from the comment in the speak function, once again, I have no luck in making that nested property to work.

What I also tried with no luck, is changing my type to:

```
type MappedCharacter = {
  name: string;
  speak: () => void;
  nestedProperties: keyof MappedCharacter['nestedProperties'];
}
```

Which results into **'nestedProperties' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation**

EDIT: 
I don't want to define a type for the "nestedProperties" object. 
I just want it to be as generic as it can be, because I cannot foresee what kind of properties it can hold.

EDIT2: 
If I have a normal object literal, without any typings, vscode CAN determine those properties, as nested as they can be. I want to achieve the same identical behaviour with types.
I usually use Vuejs for my projects, with Vetur extention, and when I define different properties for my data function, the intellisense just works.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? 
What's the missing part of the puzzle?

Comment: Maybe you should add a better interface for nested properties. I mean, you are using a generic interface that says there is an unknown key, so for intellisense the key is unknown. It just knows it's a string.

Comment: But that's exactly what I want. "nestedProperties" can have different properties, which I don't want to pre-define. Hence the generic interface.

Comment: That is the problem, how IntelliSense can possibly know what the properties will be at `nestedProperties`? It can be any meaningful string at runtime, hence it does not know what the properties will be there.

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail, what exactly do you expect to happen here as a "correct result"? Do you want to type `this.nestedProperties` in `speak()` function body and then IntelliSense to bring up the suggestion of `gunPowderAmount`?

Comment: I would like the intellisense to bring up whichever property the "nestedProperties" has.
I will update my question.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov Why if I define an object literal without a type, then the intellisense is perfectly able to do so, but with a type it "breaks"?
I would like to reproduce that behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

When you define your `MappedCharacter` type, you basically say that `nestedProperties` has *some* properties. You don't define which, so compiler doesn't have this information.

Then, you create `objectLiteral` object, where `nestedProperties` has `gunPowderAmount` property - but it's only for this particular object, and at that particular moment in time. The `speak()` function is still type-checked against `MappedCharacter` type which still doesn't have `gunPowderAmount` property defined anywhere.

I would suggest, if you know what different properites will different `MappedCharacter`'s have, define it like this, instead:

```
type MappedCharacter<TProps> = {
  name: string;
  speak: () => void;
  nestedProperties: TProps
}

type GuybrushProps = {
  gunPowderAmount: number
}

const objectLiteral: MappedCharacter<GuybrushProps> = {
  name: 'guybrush',
  nestedProperties: {
    gunPowderAmount: 1
  },
  speak () {
    // Then, intellisense here should work as you expect it to
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in the question I specified that: 

Also, I don't want to define the properties in the "nestedProperties" object. I just want it to be as generic as it can be, because I cannot foresee what kind of properties it can hold.

Sorry, if it wasn't clear.

Comment: If you cannot foresee what kind of properties it can hold, then compiler can't either, and you won't get any suggestions about these properties.

Comment: Ok but, if I have a normal object literal, without any typings, vscode CAN determine those properties, as nested as they can be. If that is possible, why with typings it is not?
Also, I usually use vuejs for my projects, with "Vetur" plugin, I don't know if you are familiar with them, although, when I define different properties for my data function, the intellisense just works. This is bugging my brain at the moment.

Comment: When you have an object literal with keys, IntelliSense uses the keys you ALREADY defined in literal. That is the difference here.

Comment: And is there absolute no way to replicate this with types? @EugeneObrezkov